# How the routes are sequenced in Sinatra if we alias the methods?

Tags: sinatra

Routes selection is different in sinatra then in rails. In rails routes.rb file is scanned top to bottom and first matching route is selected.

Sinatra associates routes with each method, in this scenario how the routes are selected if two methods are aliased.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike [Ramaze actions](http://ramaze.net/learn/getting-started)—for which this question might make sense—Sinatra's routes are not defined by the presence of methods. Rather, you use methods to define the routes, and the order in which you *call* those methods partially defines the route priority.

For example, you write:

```
get "/" do
  "Welcome!"
end

get "/products" do
  "We sell stuff!"
end
```

There are no custom "index" or "products" methods to alias. For more information, see [The Sinatra Book online](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra routing system is very versatile.

You can use method pass to jump routes. check out here [ http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro ]

```
 get '/guess/:who' do
    pass unless params[:who] == 'Frank'
    'You got me!'
  end

  get '/guess/*' do
    'You missed!'
  end
```

regards

Comment: what does "pass" mean? is there this keyword only in Sinatra?